# viewDidLoad not firing

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsviewcontroller

All,
I'm creating a windowController from my applicationDidFinishLaunching method...

```
(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
   myWC = [[myWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"myWindowControllerName"];

   [myWC showWindow:self];
}
```

At this point, the method windowDidLoad is called. From there, I call the method to load the viewController...

```
(void)windowDidLoad {
    [super windowDidLoad];

    homeScreenVC = [[HomeScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:nil];

    [baseView addSubview:[homeScreenVC view]];
}
```

While the view appears, the method viewDidLoad is not called. I tried viewDidAppear and that was not called either. I also tried loading the viewController immediately after loading the window and that also did not work. Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OSX You should use `loadView`

---

EDIT:
You can load your show `homeScreenVC` from `appDelegate`:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification{
    homeScreenVC = [[HomeScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:nil];
    [self.window.contentView addSubview:self.homeViewController.view];
    homeScreenVC.view.frame = ((NSView*)self.window.contentView).bounds;
}
```

Don't load the view here, this method gets called when the view is loaded

```
-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
    //anything you want to do when home screen is presented
}
```

Comment: @nempoBu4 `viewDidLoad` `viewDidAppear` are iOS methods, which are not available in OSX.

Comment: While loadView does get called, now the view does not draw. The view is bound to the File Owner in the nib. @GoodSp33d, Apple's docs say viewDidLoad is available in OS 10.10, but I haven't upgraded yet from 10.9 so I should have checked that first.

Comment: Got the view to finally draw and loadView is called. Thank you for the answer! I appreciate everyone's comments

Answer (score 0):

For **OSX**, **viewDidLoad**, **viewWillAppear** etc get called. They were only not calling for me for a viewController where I was using WebView control but didn't include WebKit framework. So, after adding the framework, these methods again started calling just fine.